# Infinite Doubly stochastic matrix questions

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have the following question about a Markov chain ${(X_n)}_{n \geq 0}$ with infinite irreducible doubly stochastic matrix $P$.

1. We have the state space $\{1,2,...\}$ . Determine the stationary vector $\gamma$ for $P$ if ${\gamma}_1 = 1$?
2. We have the same state space. When will ${(X_n)}_{n \geq 0}$ become positive recurrent?

   Attempt to answer to 1. We see that $\gamma =(1,1,...)$ is a solution to the problem. Is it unique? Since this is an irreducible chain (because of the doubly stochastic matrix $P$) it has unique stationary vector. (I do not see any condition about that the state space has to be finite).

   Attempt to answer 2. Well here I have no idea since the state space is infinite $\pi \to (0,0,...)$ but the sum of its entries is $1$. So we get that $m_i$ the mean recurrence time for state i is $m_i = 1/{\pi}_i \to \infty$ if we let the state space tend to infinity. So the mean recurrence time is I guess infinity based on the conclusions in 1. so it cant be positive recurrent.

I'm a little bit confused so I would love if anybody could help me.
Regards, Raxel.

Comment: a non-summable stationary vector may not be unique.  and example is simple random walk with prob p not .5 of going up.  both 1 and $(\frac pq)^n$ (or the reciprocal) are stationary.  it seems to have state space $\pm 1 , \pm2,...$ but since you can renumber the states it is ok. If there is stationary distribution (summable) then there are no non summable positive etc.'s so it cannot be recurrent.

Comment: @Byron Schmuland, your previous photo was more normalized than this one)) you seem funny and crazy))

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I'm a pretty boring person in real life, so I thought I'd take a crazy picture to compensate!